# NavigateBackward broken in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Say you are in location X.
F12 to function foo in foo.cpp (Open in Preview Mode)
F12 to function bar in bar.cpp (Preview mode, foo.cpp disappear).
Navigate Back (Ctrl-) will take you back to X. Expected to go back to foo.

This is very annoying. Anyway to workaround?

Comment: I didn't know about this hotkey -- it's exactly what I was looking for, and it appears to work just fine. At least in Update 1.